# Checking for a pinned message in C# discord

Tags: c#, discord

i'm trying to make a purge command in C# Discord that removes x amount of messages and then checks if they are pinned and if they are the Bot doesn't purge them. Right now i have done everything but to check if they are pinned, i have looked around and i haven't found any good/complete documentation. (i don't really know where to look so if you know something please tell me). Any and all answears will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a `pinned` field on message objects which indicates if the messages are pinned or not: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object (second to last field in the table).

I don't know the details about this API but seems like that would do what you want.

Comment: Thank you this really helped me, i can't beleve that i missed that but again thank you!

Comment: Sometimes you just have to write it out and facepalm over something you've been missing. All part of the learning curve!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the official Discord API presents the message object with a "pinned" bool, as can be seen here:

https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object

However, it looks like based on your tags, you're using Discord.NET. I looked through the documentation, and I'm having a hard time finding any place that the "pinned" bool is implemented there. It's referenced in this issue.

https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/168

Maybe the "IsPinned" bool is implemented in one of the models or overriden where I can't search it? Maybe provide some of your code where you're downloading the messages. Iterating through them might reveal the IsPinned attribute.

EDIT: It looks like the `IsPinned` attribute is implemented in the dev branch. That looks to be what you are looking for. The library is in beta, so it makes sense that they're still ramping up some stuff.